# Format Calculated Data

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to format of years and months in a manner like yy-mm

I can calculate like this to get my year value:

```
ROUND(months_between(sysdate,hiringdate)/12)
```

And this to get the months value:

```
ROUND(months_between(sysdate,hiringdate))
```

I just dont know how to combine those 2 to get them in the yy-mm format

Comment: convert to strings and then concat with +

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a database tag.

Comment: Are you sure you only want to use 2 digits for years?  That can cause trouble.

Comment: @Tom well it just the numbers of total years in between today and their hiring date. 2 digits is all that is necessary for that information

Comment: @user11119624 You need to tag the question with the appropriate database tag, and add your sample data to the question itself.

Answer (score 2):

This looks like Oracle, so try this:

```
select (lpad(floor(months_between(sysdate, hiringdate)/12), 2, '0') || '-' ||
        lpad(mod(floor(months_between(sysdate, hiringdate)), 12), 2, '0')
       ) as yymm
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends: there are many flavors of SQL.

In Oracle and standard SQL, you can use `string1 || string2` ,

In MySQL there's the `CONCAT(string1, string2)` function

In SAS there's the `COMPRESS(string1 || string2)` statement, which looks like a combination of the above.

Search how to do it on your platform or let it know which one it is.

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this. Using the `EMP` table in the `SCOTT` schema for testing.

```
select empno, ename, hiredate,
       to_char(floor(mths/12), 'fm99') || '-' || 
       to_char(mod(mths, 12) , 'fm00')  as yymm
from   ( 
         select empno, ename, hiredate, 
                round(months_between(sysdate, hiredate)) as mths
         from   scott.emp
       )
;
     EMPNO ENAME      HIREDATE    YYMM   
---------- ---------- ----------- -------
      7369 SMITH      17-DEC-1980 38-03  
      7499 ALLEN      20-FEB-1981 38-01  
      7521 WARD       22-FEB-1981 38-01  
      7566 JONES      02-APR-1981 38-00  
      7654 MARTIN     28-SEP-1981 37-06  
      7698 BLAKE      01-MAY-1981 37-11  
      7782 CLARK      09-JUN-1981 37-09  
      7788 SCOTT      19-APR-1987 31-11  
      7839 KING       17-NOV-1981 37-04  
      7844 TURNER     08-SEP-1981 37-06  
      7876 ADAMS      23-MAY-1987 31-10  
      7900 JAMES      03-DEC-1981 37-04  
      7902 FORD       03-DEC-1981 37-04  
      7934 MILLER     23-JAN-1982 37-02
```

Answer (score -1):

Probably a million ways to do this. One of them is this one:

```
SELECT RIGHT (CAST (YEAR (GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(4)), 2) + '-' + RIGHT ('0' + CAST (MONTH (GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR (2)), 2)
```

Comment: How would you go about doing it with TO_CHAR?

Comment: Neither `RIGHT` nor `YEAR` nor `GETDATE` are Oracle functions.

Comment: @WernfriedDomscheit - in fairness to this responder, the OP originally tagged the question simply as `sql`. He added the `oracle` tag 20 minutes **after** this Answer was posted.